# Heroku - NodeJS - Using node-dateTime and sqlite for dyno

Tags: heroku, node.js

Built a Discord node.js bot that utilizes sqlite and node-dateTime. Works great locally. Setup Github and Heroku which are communicating with each other, but upon build (which succeeds), then returns an error for "node-dateTime" dependencies. Does Heroku's buildpacks not support dateTime?

Also, my sqlite will store information from my Discord server. Is this okay through Heroku?

Any insight into this issue would be helpful.

Comment: Hi bighiggens, while Heroku is a Salesforce product, I think you'll have more luck getting an answer to this question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

That module should be fine. Where is it included in your package.json? It sounds like you might have it inside `devDependencies` and it's not being included during the build process.

SQLite won’t work on Heroku since it uses an ephemeral filesystem: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem You’ll probably want to use Postgres or Mongo.

This post might help overall: https://github.com/synicalsyntax/discord.js-heroku

Comment: This is how it's written in my package.json:
`"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2",
    "node-datetime": "^2.1.0",
    "sqlite": "^3.0.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  }`

Comment: That should be fine, then. This makes me think like it could be another issue not related to Heroku. Could you update your original post with the errors you're seeing?